# Кнопка внутри кнопки

Tags: html, jquery, button

Подскажите есть возможность создать кнопку внутри кнопки и чтобы логика у них была разная? Не нашел примеров. Не судите строго начинающих и накидайте примеров пожалуйста, если есть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#in {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button id="out" onclick="console.log(this.id)">
Outside 1
<div id="in" onclick="console.log(this.id);event.stopPropagation();">Inside</div>
Outside 2
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно :)

Comment: Вообще то это див внутри кнопки, а не кнопка в кнопке))